# Syntax error when defining time with colon

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I cannot correct this mistake for the life of me, when I run this script, it gives me a syntax error.

```
def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours number, number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[0])
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: can you post your syntax error?

Comment: What are you expecting the syntax `tm:'hours:minutes'` to do?

Comment: @BrenBarn i dont know about the tm: part, thats just what i was told to do.  I need to define the time with a colon, and that wont work when i run the script.

Comment: Function annotations (the part after the first colon in `tm:'hours:minutes'`) aren't supported in Python 2 - are you using Python 3.something?

Comment: @JBaczuk it just says syntax error and highlights the colon.  For example, i run the script and input (1:13) and it highlights that colon

Comment: @JaredBanton -- Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @mgilson def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours

    number, number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[0])       **** ================================
>>> 
>>> extract_minutes(1:03)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It works as-is for me (Python 3.4.1).

Comment: When running the script, are you putting quotes around the time - `extract_hours("1:13")` vs. `extract_hours(1:13)`?

Comment: @Dan that's what I was thinking, see edit to answer.

Comment: all i had to do was use quotes i guess... thanks for the help

Comment: @JaredBanton why have you asked this **exact same question** twice?

Answer (score 0):

just pass a string into your function:

```
def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours number, number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[0])
```

and call it like:

```
extract_hours('1:13')
```

Comment: I need it to look like this to fit the constraints: def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):

Comment: did you call it like this?  extract_hours('1:13') as a string?

Comment: `tm:'hours:minutes'` is python 3 function annotation.

Comment: @levi thanks didn't realize that.  It shouldn't really change the behavior, though, right?  (If you call it correctly)

Comment: @JBaczuk yep. That is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the function with a string

```
def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours number,    number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[0])
```

Call the function:

```
>>> extract_hours("12:34")
    12
>>>
```